# Can't connect to mysql database remotely ERROR 2003

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I want to connect from server A to mysql database on server B. Let's say A's ip is IPA, and B's is IPB. I've done two things:

1. added **#bind-address = IPA** in **my.cnf** file on server B and restarted mysql;
2. granted all privileges to user on server A that is trying to connect to B's database using this line:

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'userA'@'IPA' WITH GRANT OPTION;

and restarted mysql.

Still, executing this on server A:

```
mysql -uUserA  -pPassA -hIPA
```

gives me error:
**ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IPA' (110)**

Comment: `#bind-address = IPA` is wrong for two reasons: 1. It has no effect because of the `#`, which makes it a comment, and 2. that should be `IPB`. You can't bind to another server's IP.

Comment: Does it even affect what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It might, or might not, depending on the default value of that, the rest of your config, the options with which MySQL was built, etc. There's no way for me to tell for sure. All I know is that you tried to do something in a way that would not work, so I was pointing it out. I was not trying to answer your question, otherwise I would have written an answer. But did you actually change it and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Have you made sure that server's firewall, PC's firewall, network's firewall and antivirus firewall all allow this type of connection?

Comment: 1/ Check if your MySQL bind to 127.0.0.1 or IPB or 0.0.0.0 (on Linux, netstat -nal | grep 3306)     2/ Check firewall.

Comment: @KenCheung, here are the answers:
1) 0.0.0.0:3306, no matter what my bind-address is, so I removed that line completely; 2) Used **/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s IPA -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT** and **service iptables save**, but still can't connect.

Comment: For the iptables, please -I (Insert) instead of -A (Append) to ensure this ACCEPT rule is "higher" than any potential blocking rules.  Then, if you don't mind, try to grant to 'userA'@'%' (this allows client from any IP instead of the specific IP address) and protect your MySQL by iptables.